# Render a text component when Image (from react-native) throws onError

Tags: image, react-native

On failure in image loading, I want to render a text component through onError function from  component.

I have tried using this, but failed! (though onError is getting triggered)

```
 View style={styles.imgView}>
              <Image
                source={{
                  uri: `https://google.com/icon/tags/${value}.png`,
                }}
                style={styles.imageStyle}
                onError={() => { 
                return(
                  <Text size="S" white>
                    {value}
                  </Text>
                );
                  }}
              />
            </View>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not right, do the following,

```
    constructor() {
       this.state = {
          isError: false
       }
    }
    render() {
     return (
      <View style={styles.imgView}>
        {this.state.isError? (
          <Text size="S" white>
            {value}
          </Text>
        ): <Image
        source={{
          uri: `https://google.com/icon/tags/${value}.png`,
        }}
        style={styles.imageStyle}
        onError={this.imageLoadError}
      />}
    </View>
     )
    }

    imageLoadError = () => {
       this.setState({
          isError: true
       })
    }
```